# Ruby: share common variables and methods across a set of scripts

Tags: ruby

I have a directory full of ruby scripts for common tasks, and I've started to accumulate a set of common variables and methods that I find myself defining in each new script. The next step in improving this would seem to be creating a file (say, commonstuff.rb) and "require"ing that file from the other scripts so that the common variables and methods are all available everywhere and defined only once.

A simple attempt that didn't work:

commonstuff.rb

```
username=ENV['USER']
home_dir_path=ENV['HOME']

def print_and_execute(command, &block)
  puts command

  process_io = IO.popen(command + "2>&1")

  while(line=process_io.gets)
    if (block != nil)
      yield line
    else
      puts line
      STDOUT.flush
    end
  end
end
```

script1.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/common_stuff'

puts home_dir_path         # Fail
print_and_execute "date"   # Fail
```

I've used ruby libraries and frameworks, but I don't have any of that available in my current environment. I just have straight ruby, and I'm a little rusty on some of the basic idioms that would work well here, or that would look right to a ruby expert.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap your methods and variables in a [module](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html), e.g.

```
module CommonStuff
    USERNAME=ENV['USER']
    HOME_DIR_PATH=ENV['HOME']

    def print_and_execute(command, &block)
        ...
    end
end
```

Then script1.rb might be like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/commonstuff.rb'
include CommonStuff

puts HOME_DIR_PATH         # Win
print_and_execute "date"   # Win
```

Or, if you don't want to include the module in your namespace:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/commonstuff.rb'

puts CommonStuff::HOME_DIR_PATH         # Win
CommonStuff.print_and_execute "date"   # Win
```

See also [Modules](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/modules.html) and [the Programming Ruby page on modules](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_modules.html).

Comment: That's pretty much what I did, I have a RubyToolkit module with all the things I need (config file processing, logging, etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use capital letters for your constants (HOME_DIR_PATH, not home_dir_path)
2. Put your methods inside a module.

You can call your methods through the module, or you can include the module in your namespace and call them directly (Sarah has code for all of this)

Comment: Thanks!
For the benefit of others that come across this, it looks like the constants (yes, I should have said "constants" in the question, not "variables") can stay outside the module definition.

Also, after putting the methods inside a module, I had to use an additional "include" statement to include that module in scripts that make use of its functions.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't put constants like that in the module, since they aren't likely to cause collisions in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler solution. A module is not needed. I noticed you may have a mismatch in file name: You said you named your common file 'commonstuff.rb', but you require it with an underscore as 'common_stuff':

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/common_stuff'
```

Fix that with:

```
require_relative 'commonstuff'   # require_relative if ruby >= 1.9
```

Your method should now work and we just need to make your variables accessible. Methods, globals, and constants are all imported into your namespace when you require a file, so simply change your variables to CONSTANTS (as another user suggested):

```
USERNAME = ENV['USER']
HOME_DIR_PATH = ENV['HOME']
```

or make them $globals:

```
$username = ENV['USER']
$home_dir_path = ENV['HOME']
```

You might want to use $global variables over CONSTANTS if you will redefine the variables while running. You can redefine constants, but ruby will generate a warning as it's not considered good practice.